# EXCEL TO TXT file export

Tags: excel, export, notepad, txt

can anyone help me with this one?
I need to save a excel spreadsheet into .txt file however if there is 8 characters in certain cell txt file adds another TAB which can't be really there as another program doesn't pull the information if it's there. I am out of ideas.

Comment: What ideas did you have already?

Comment: I tried to save is as dozen of different formats, change the format of actual cell etc but always the same outcome - if it is 8 characters or more it adds TAB.